# Docker find all layers in an image

Tags: docker

Docker has changed it's backend and now the "docker history" command no longer shows layer IDs of all layers in an image. More details here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20131

Although I understand why it's showing "missing", I still havent found a new way to extract the information I'm looking for. Does anyone know how I can find all the layers in an image? I'd like to be able to cross-reference layers over different images so that I know when a certain layer is used by more than once service, which is why I used the ID shown in the history command up until recentely.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.